# what is boost::empty_init_t used for?

Tags: c++, boost

I am reading `boost::empty_value` [source code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/core/empty_value.hpp) and don't understand the usage of `boost::empty_init_t`. In the `empty_value` specialized template code (I removed some inactive `#ifdefine` blocks):

```
template<class T, unsigned N>
class empty_value<T, N, true>
    : T {
public:
    typedef T type;

    empty_value() = default;

    empty_value(boost::empty_init_t)
        : T() { }

    template<class... Args>
    explicit empty_value(boost::empty_init_t, Args&&... args)
        : T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }


    const T& get() const BOOST_NOEXCEPT {
        return *this;
    }

    T& get() BOOST_NOEXCEPT {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Would not one constructor like the following be enough?:

```
template<class... Args>
    explicit empty_value(Args&&... args)
        : T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }
```

Why does the `empty_value` implementation need another two constructor?:

```
empty_value() = default;

empty_value(boost::empty_init_t)
        : T() { }
```

Another question is: what is the `typedef T type;` for?

Answer (score 2):

I also wrote an email to the author Glen Fernandes, here is his reply. Hope it could help others:

---

There are now only 2 constructors documented:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/core/doc/html/core/empty_value.html

1. `empty_value() = default;`
2. `template<class... Args> empty_value(empty_init_t, Args&&... args);`

The last one is not enough because the first one does something
different. It performs default-initialization, while the last one
performs value-initialization.

i.e. It is the difference between:

1. `new(storage) T;`
2. `new(storage) T();`

For example, default-initialization for primitive types means do
nothing. Value-initialization for primitive types means initialize to
zero.

e.g. Consider `empty_value<S>` where `struct S { int a[10000]; };`

Here  constructor 1 does no work. But constructor 2 will initialize
all 10,000 integers to zero (which is expensive, so the user might
want to opt out of that).

The 'type' typedef is just something I found useful a few times when I
had: `typedef empty_value<'complex type expression'> base;`

i.e. To easily get `'complex type expression'` as `base::type` rather
than repeat it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The tag `boost::empty_init_t` allows you to differentiate between

```
T value;    // default initialization
```

and

```
T value();  // value initialization (warn: most vexing parse)
```

These two types of initializations do different things in general and with a single constructor

```
template<class... Args>
explicit empty_value(Args&&... args) 
    : T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

there is no way to default-initialize base class `T`.

For example, if `T` is

```
struct T {
    int i;
}
```

then `empty_value()` will leave `T.i` uninitialized, whereas `empty_value(boost::empty_init_t)` will initialize `T.i` to zero. See this simple [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Qb_m4z).

> What is the `typedef T type;` for?

To simplify extraction of the underlying type from the `empty_value<...>` type itself. With this alias you can simply write `typename Empty_value_type::type` to get `T`. This can be useful in generic code:

```
template<class Empty_value_type>
void foo(Empty_value_type) {
    using my_type = typename Empty_value_type::type;
}
```